# Android version of html image map

Tags: android, html

is there a way I can show an image in my app, and detect when a certain part of it has been clicked; like you can do in HTML with an image map - defining areas of the image in co-ordinates?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most (all?) of the objects we use on the UI inherit the `View` class, which means that they inherit the `onTouchEvent` method of the `View` class.

Decide which subclass is appropriate for you and then utilize the `onTouchEvent` method to trigger what ever code you need based on the coordinate output from `onTouchEvent`.

Comment: that is what I plan to do, for example; I have a picture of a house, how can I tell if the user hase clicked on the window? In an html image map I can define a rectangle of ID X, with the coordinates of x1,y1 - x2,y2. Can I reproduce this in android?

Comment: I have found an algorithm to do the coordinate stuff I want. As the answer above is technically right it is marked as answered.